# macOS - sendmail - postfix messages

Tags: postfix, smtp, sendmail

My app is attempting to use sendmail to send an email message. I can see the email's sitting in `/var/spool/postfix/maildrop`but for some reason which I need help figuring out, the postfix pickup service is not sending them out?? - how to debug?

Comment: **Logs.** On startup, and during operation, postfix will spew out useful diagnostics, and that is almost always where you want to start figuring out what is going on.

Comment: Where at? I can’t find them